# How to Order Xunit TestClasses

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, automated-tests, xunit

Is it possible to run test classes in order? Without disabling the parallel execution for the whole framework?

I have found this:
https://github.com/tomaszeman/Xunit.Extensions.Ordering#test-cases-ordering

In order to run classes in order, I need to create AssemblyInfo.cs and add following lines in AssemblyInfo.cs

```
using Xunit;
//Optional
[assembly: CollectionBehavior(DisableTestParallelization = true)]
//Optional
[assembly: TestCaseOrderer("Xunit.Extensions.Ordering.TestCaseOrderer", 
"Xunit.Extensions.Ordering")]
//Optional
[assembly: TestCollectionOrderer("Xunit.Extensions.Ordering.CollectionOrderer", 
"Xunit.Extensions.Ordering")]
```

This causes to run whole framework with only one thread.

I would like to accomplish to put classes in order in selected Collection
For instance I have collection ("sequentialRun")

```
Collection[("sequentialRun"),Order(1)]
Class A{

[Fact]
void test1(){}
[Fact]
void test2(){}

}

Collection[("sequentialRun"),Order(2)]
Class B{

[Fact]
void test1(){}
[Fact]
void test2(){}
}

Class C{

[Fact]
void test1(){}
[Fact]
void test2(){}
}
```

When I trigger the whole test script in my framework I would like to achieve that A and C starts running together and when A is done then B can start. Is there anyway to accomplish this??

Thank you so much!!

Comment: Why do you want/have to run the tests in a particular order?

Comment: I have set up a e2e test framework with xUnit-Selenium-.NET, in some cases I need to run test classes in order. I have accomplished to run test methods in order.